# How to use " rm !(*keyword) in bash 4.1.2?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I got bash 4.1.2 on remote centos machine.

When using my favorite

```
rm !(*keyword)
```

I got

```
bash: !: event not found
```

I tried to upgrade its bash, but seems the edition remains after upgrade.

The same code works well on my bash 4.3.11 on local Ubuntu machine.

How to use that command in this Bash version(4.1.2)?

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` in all `bash` versions.

Comment: That helps! But I think I need try search to find out what does it mean.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I got it by reading GNU manuals, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'll just give the answer for the question. You need to enable `extglob` to make bash recognize extended patterns besides the history expansion syntax.

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*keyword)
```

`shopt -s extglob` also enables extended pattern matching on `case` and `[[ ]]` but it's already the default behaviour in `[[ ]]` starting Bash 4.1 and extended patterns are already recognized with or without the option enabled.

For reference, see Bash Manual's  [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

Comment: You also need to disable history expansion to prevent the `!` from being parsed as such before the shell gets to the filename generation.